# Bad formatting: Add JSON data to existing URL

Tags: ios, json, post, request

I need to send request like this:

```
"http://api.site.com/login?q={"meta":{"api_key":"cb2f734a14ee3527b3"},"request":{"id":"username@host.name","password":"passw0rd"}}`
```

...the response to which should look like `{"id":399205,"token":"d43f8b2fe37aa19ac7057701"}` To do so, I have tried the following code:

```
self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSDictionary *apiKeyDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"cb2f734a14ee3527b3" forKey:@"api_key"];
NSDictionary *idPasswordDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"tc-d@gmail.com",@"id", @"abc",@"password", nil];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:apiKeyDict, @"meta", idPasswordDict, @"request", nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.site.com/login?="];
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection) {
    self.recievedData = [NSMutableData data];
}
```

Later on, I get in the following:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[self.recievedData appendData:data];
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}
```

The response data comes back as "`<h1>CHttpException</h1><p>wrong sign</p>`" As I understand, the way of adding json data to the current url is not appropriate in this case.  Does anyone have advice on how I can fix this?

resolve my problem. Convert posted json to appended string to base url-string. that's how I did it:

```
NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSMutableString *dictString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithData:requestData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[dictString insertString:@"http://api.site.com/login?q=" atIndex:0];

//don't know why but dictString contains a lot of @"\n" and spaces to present it nice-formated.
[dictString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"" options:nil range:NSMakeRange(0, dictString.length)];
[dictString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"" options:nil range:NSMakeRange(0, dictString.length)];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[dictString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

if it helps someone will appreciate tick near this issue=)

Comment: Right off, Your example at the top is showing a GET rather than a POST.   GET uses params in the URL, where POST sends data in the message body.

Comment: You tried to set query parameters to the URL, but you didn't actually set any. Thus, the error response (in HTML). You should consult the API documentation of the web service. Possibly, you need a different Content-Type. Or just try the URL omitting the partial query string (the two characters "?=").

Comment: @KHansenSF Actually, a POST request may have query params in the URL - this is just rarely done in practice. ;)

Comment: so how can I add json-format string to url? I've heard about some json representation but haven't found it=( can it be helpful in my problev?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it right using AFNetworking library - it's easy to implement and to work with. Whole code you need in this case is quite simple and it was always working well for me.

```
NSDictionary *apiKeyDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"cb2f734a14ee3527b3" forKey:@"api_key"];
NSDictionary *idPasswordDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"tc-d@gmail.com",@"id", @"abc",@"password", nil];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:apiKeyDict, @"meta", idPasswordDict, @"request", nil];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *urlString = @"http://api.site.com/login";
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonString, @"q", nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil parameters:parameters];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        //OK
        NSLog(@"%@", JSON);
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        //Response failed
    }];
    [operation start];
```